# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in Spring MVC JSP

Tags: javascript, html, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to pass a model attribute of a jsp as a parameter to two javascript functions (the functions are in their own '.js' file) when the page loads. The model attribute is a list of strings given by a Spring-MVC Controller. Currently, whenever I load the page, I get an 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' error, and can't seem to find why.

The Spring-MVC Controller

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value="/passToJS")
    public String getPassToJSPage(ModelMap modelMap) {
        modelMap.addAttribute("names", nameService.getNames());
        return "passToJSPage";
    }
```

The Relevant parts of the jsp

```
<head>
    <script type=text/javascript src="<c:url value="/resources/js/nameReport.js" />"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript src="<c:url value="/resources/js/nameChart.js" />"></script>
</head>

<body onload="calculateNameReport(${names}); calculateNameChart(${names});">
```

Finally, the javascript
calculateNameReport -

```
/* exported calculateNameReport*/
function calculateNameRepot(names) {

    display(names) //This works fine
}
```

calculateNameChart -

```
/* exported makeNameChart */
function makeNameChart(names) {
    chart(name) //this works fine
}
```

I'm not entirely sure why I am getting the exception, it seems like the parameters are getting passed to the functions correctly.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: try please with apostrophe calculateNameReport('${names}');

Answer (score 1):

The string values there should be quoted:

```
<body onload="calculateNameReport('${names}'); calculateNameChart('${names}');">
<!--------------------------------^--------^----------------------^--------^
```

The above gets executed as JavaScript and there won't be the final string as a variable. It should be passed as a value instead. So enclosing them inside `'` so as to avoid the clash between `"` of the attribute.

Comment: I tried that, and it seems as though JS is treating the list as though it was a string, and my output is roughly along the lines of '[,n,a,m,e.......]' is that the expected behavior? My goal is to have something more like ["string1", "string2",....]

Comment: @B.Dubs No buddy. The problem exists in your JSP. Kindly correct that.